# How to decrease markdown header level in visual mode without a plugin?

Tags: visual-mode, filetype-markdown

I have a file like this:

```
# Heading A

### Heading B1

lorem ipsum

### Heading B2 

lorem ipsum
```

and I want to reduce the header levels of B1 and B2 to look like this:

```
# Heading A

## Heading B1

lorem ipsum

## Heading B2 

lorem ipsum
```

I know how to increase markdown header levels from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22150165).

I know [this plugin](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown) can increase and decrease header levels but it's only for the original markdown flavor. I want to avoid plugins because I want to be able to do this for pandoc (and potentially other markdown flavors).

I searched Google but couldn't find anything helpful (for my level of knowledge).

How can I *decrease* the markdown header level in visual mode without a plugin?

**Update December 10, 2019.** Thanks for the answers! I've been using this custom command for a while in my init.vim (using Neovim now) and it seems to work well. Sorry, I can't remember clearly where I got this from. I think I combined [apparat's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13067/13618) with plasticboy's [HeaderDecrease function](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/blob/master/ftplugin/markdown.vim).

```
command! -range HeaderIncrease <line1>,<line2>s/^#/##
command! -range HeaderDecrease <line1>,<line2>s/^##/#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply search for two #s at the beginning of the line an replace it with one #.

Normal mode global replace:

```
:%s/^##/#/g
```

and for visual mode:

```
'<,'>s/^##/#/g
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Doesn't seem to work in visual mode though. I receive the error: `E488: Trailing characters`. The exact command I'm running: `'<,'>%s/^##/#/g`. However, your answer does work in normal mode and on the entire file. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Iota % means: 'use all the file as range' and '<,'> means ' "use visual selection as range" so, if you start a command from visual mode, the range is already provided for you and then, adding '%' raises The error `E488: Trailing characters` then, the command would be: `'<,'>s/^##/#/` or  `'<,'>s/^##/#/g`

Comment: @rbernabe Removing the `%` in visual mode works! Thanks!

Comment: @rbernabe thanks, I added this to the answer

Comment: Or even fewer keystrokes: `:'<,'>s/^#//`, which just removes the first `#` from any line that starts with a `#`. (Note that the `g` is unnecessary in your version, too).

Answer (score 1):

@apparat gave you the correct answer, but I it can be made into filetype specific mappings for ease of use.

Put the following into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim`:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> ]# :keeppatterns s/^/#/e<cr>
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> [# :keeppatterns s/^#//e<cr>
xnoremap <buffer> <silent> [# :<c-u>keeppatterns '<,'>g/^#/keeppatterns s/^#//<cr>
xnoremap <buffer> <silent> ]# :<c-u>keeppatterns '<,'>g/^#/keeppatterns s/^#/##/<cr>
```

Notes:

- This uses `:keeppatterns` so requires a never Vim (I think Vim 8+)
- Uses a substitution so it will affect the `&` and `g&`.
- Overwrites `]#`/`[#` mappings. However these are rather useless in markdown

Answer (score 1):

Without a plugin you'll likely have a very imperfect solution.

Indeed, while a leading `#` is a good sign for a header, it may unfortunately appear in other contexts: in code contexts. If in your markdown text you're likely to have snippets of bash script, Python, Perl, or many others, all the `:[range]s/^#` solutions will alter your snippets which you won't want.

If you only have very few headers or bash/perl/... comments, you can use the *confirm*  flag of `:substitute`. Otherwise, well, you'll dream of something able to distinguish embedded code snippets from headers.

Recently, in my [TOC generator](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/autoload/lh/markdown/toc.vim) I've used a state-machine to ignore code snippets. The code snippets identification is done with the following

````
let lines = getline(1, '$')
" First remove blocks of code
let blocks = map(copy(lines), 'v:val =~ "^\\s*```" ? (v:key + 1) : -1')
call filter(blocks, 'v:val > 0')
````

From there, `[0, block[0])` defines the first block of line numbers without a code snippet. `(block[1], blocks[2])` the second block and so on.From here, you'll want to intersect those lines numbers with the total range on which you'll want to apply the substitution.

```
 let blocks = [1] + blocks + [line('$')]
 let text_ranges = map(range(len(blocks)/2), '[blocks[2*v:val]-1, blocks[2*v:val+1]+1]')
 " Filter out ranges out side the selected range (a:firstline, a:lastline) -- untested
 call filter(text_ranges, 'v:val[1] >= a:firstline') 
 call filter(text_ranges, 'v:val[0] <= a:lastline')
 let text_ranges[0][0] = max(text_ranges[0][0], a:firstline)
 let text_ranges[-1][0] = min(text_ranges[-1][0], a:lastline)
 " And finally apply the substitutions (see the other answers)
 for range in text_ranges
     " todo: make sure range isn't empty
     " add one level
     exe range[0].','.range[1].'s/^##/#/'
 endfor
```

As you can see, this is not trivial, this is one of the reasons we write plugins. BTW, we still have to wrap these lines in a range-function which is to be called from a command.