# How to use :g to insert?

Tags: global-command

Let's say I have these lines:

```
a
# c
b
## d
```

and i want to insert `#` on a line starting with a `#` so that I get this:

```
a
## c
b
### d
```

I was not able to find anything in the vim help, but I was able to get this far: `g/^#/` - what should come after the second `/`?

Comment: While the question is technically not the same, I suspect your need is identical to one expressed in that Q/A (https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13065/how-to-decrease-markdown-header-level-in-visual-mode-without-a-plugin). Am I right?

Comment: Using substitute Isn't exactly the samebecause if there is a hash in the middle of the line and that would also be changed

Comment: No it won't. The pattern to search isn't `#` but `^#`. `:substitute` really is the way to go. Beside that wasn't my question. My question is: what's your exact need? Is it about refactoring markdown?

Comment: Ah I see, my bad. And yes I am refactoring markdown. I guess it is almost duplicate question then?

Comment: In spirit yes. Other people may be interested in the technical solution that mixes `global + normal`, though. What's interesting in the other question, is that the objective is more extensively covered. For instance, I provide a non trivial way to refactor headings while leaving shebangs and `# comments` intact in code snippets when that matters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What comes after the second `/` is an Ex command. In this case you could use
the `:normal` command, which executes its argument as if you typed it in normal
mode (see [`:help :normal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3anormal))

```
:g/^#/normal I#
```

or the `:substitute` command (see [`:help :substitute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3asubstitute))

```
:g/^#/substitute/^/#/
" Or just
:g/^#/s/^/#/
```

but also you could use the `:substitute` command without the `:g` like so:

```
:%s/^\ze#/#/
" or
:%s/^#/#&/
```

See [`:help /\ze`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5cze) and 
[`:help s/\&`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#s%2f%5c%26) for more
information.