# Remove one level of all Vimwiki headers in a selection

Tags: visual-mode, plugin-vimwiki

In Vimwiki, a header level can be decreased, by [pressing](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/blob/96b139253db1d55dc01d530db87286846e5e5752/doc/vimwiki.txt#L405) `-`.

Is there a *native* Vimwiki command to remove a level from all headers within a visual selection?

Keep in mind that Vimwiki supports a number of formats (e.g., `=== Header level 3 ===`, `### Header level 3`). A search/replace, or a [custom command, or a plugin](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/13065/14785) might be a solution. But I am curious if Vimwiki already supports this out-of-the-box?

Comment: Reading [the doc](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/blob/master/doc/vimwiki.txt) doesn't seem to yield such a command but you could create your own one combining [`-`](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/blob/master/doc/vimwiki.txt#L399) and (`]]`)[https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/blob/master/doc/vimwiki.txt#L413) maybe a macro like `qqq` (clean the `q` register) then `qq]]-@q`: create a macro which goes to the next heading, decrease it then call the macro recursively if `]]` doesn't wrap around the file (I didn't test it)

Comment: Otherwise you'll need to  create a function which does `-]]` and checks if you didn't wrap around the file.

Comment: With the right pattern (`^===\|###`?) you could use `:global/pat/normal -`